# In Gradle, can we (and how) get path of artifact built by moduleA in moduleB?

Tags: gradle

we have multi-module Gradle project with multiple artifacts (some of them are binary artifacts) built by different modules.

In module A, we need to define "Exec" task which runs some binary built by module B. in Exec Task, path to this binary must be configured in configuration phase. Module B exports this binary as artifact (so artifact path is also configured in configuration path). The problem is that we can't control the order in which the module is configured, so when we configure binary for execTask in module A it will fail because moduleB has not been configured yet (modules are configured in alphabetical order, but changing module names is not valid solution).

Please don't ask me why we need to run binary in execution phase of the project the binary was built...... We have our reasons...

Something like the following example (I tried to make the code as small as possible):

**moduleA**

```
configurations {
  withbinary
}

dependencies {
  withbinary project(path: ':moduleB', configuration: 'binaryfile')
}

task execTask(type: Exec, dependsOn: configurations.withbinary) {
  String binary = project(":moduleB").configurations.binaryfile.artifacts.toArray()[0].getFile().getAbsolutePath()
  commandLine "${binary}"
  args ...
}
```

**moduleB**

```
task binarybuildertask(...) {
 ...
}

configurations {
  binaryfile
}

artifacts {
  binaryfile file: xxxx/binaryfile, extension: 'bin', name: "binaryfile", type: 'binary', builtBy: binarybuildertask
}
```

We use Gradle 1.11 & 1.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can control what order projects are configured in.

```
evaluationDependsOn ':moduleB'
```

Comment: Due to my fresh account, I can't vote up your comment, but it seems it helped. I don't know why, but I always thought that 'evaluationDependsOn' affects only the execution phase so I've never tried it. Thank you!